# XSLT Template to filter duplicates on the same node of xml with NameSpace

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi folks,
                 I have a situation where I need to filter the duplicates existing on the same node using XSLT template. Following is the input xml which has two entries of "**Don Jon**" and I want to remove this in the output using ***CustomerID***. I tried a sample provided in this [URL](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalksyn/archive/2005/12/19/mapping_3a00_-inline-xslt-scenario.aspx) and wasn't successful as I am not sure how to do this when NameSpace exists. I would appreciate if someone guide me in the right direction to fix this issue.

**Input XML:**

```
<Response xmlns="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS">
  <Result>
    <Output>
      <Orders>
        <Order>
          <OrderID>90123</OrderID>
          <CustomerID>1234</CustomerID>          
        </Order>
        <Order>
          <OrderID>90124</OrderID>
          <CustomerID>1235</CustomerID>
        </Order>
        <Order>
          <OrderID>90125</OrderID>
          <CustomerID>1236</CustomerID>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Customers>
        <Customer>
          <CustomerFullName>Don Jon</CustomerFullName>
          <CustomerID>1234</CustomerID>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
          <CustomerFullName>Kevin Smith</CustomerFullName>
          <CustomerID>1235</CustomerID>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
          <CustomerFullName>Don Jon</CustomerFullName>
          <CustomerID>1234</CustomerID>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
          <CustomerFullName>Peter Parker</CustomerFullName>
          <CustomerID>1236</CustomerID>
        </Customer>
      </Customers>
    </Output>
  </Result>
</Response>
```

**Output XML I am expecting:**

```
  <Customers>
    <Customer>
      <CustomerFullName>Don Jon</CustomerFullName>
      <CustomerID>1234</CustomerID>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <CustomerFullName>Kevin Smith</CustomerFullName>
      <CustomerID>1235</CustomerID>
    </Customer>       
    <Customer>
      <CustomerFullName>Peter Parker</CustomerFullName>
      <CustomerID>1236</CustomerID>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
```

**My Attempt:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template name="CustomersTemplate" xmlns:ns="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS">

    <xsl:variable name="Unique-CustomerNum" select="//ns:Result/ns:Output/ns:Customers/ns:Customer[not(ns:CustomerID=preceding-sibling::ns:Customer/ns:CustomerID)]/ns:CustomerID" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$Unique-CustomerNum">

      <Customer>        
        <xsl:for-each select="//ns:Customer[ns:CustomerID=current()]">
          <CustomerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:CustomerFullName" />
          </CustomerID>        
        </xsl:for-each>        
      </Customer>

    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First, the article you point to is not a good source - see [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) why and how to do this correctly (**in XSLT 1.0**). Secondly, the question of dealing with namespaces is a separate one.

Comment: To deal with the namespace, declare a prefixed namespace like `xmlns:r="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS"` in your stylesheet header and prefix your XPath selectors in your expressions: `r:Customer/r:CustomerID`.

Comment: Thanks Helderdarocha. I will try and let you know if that works

Comment: I am still not successful. I added the xslt I tried above. Please let me know if there is something wrong in my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the customers by their ID using a key. Check the link provided my @michael.hor257k, which explains [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). To apply it to your problem you need to define a map containing all customers, which you can retrieve with a `CustomerID`. That's a `<xsl:key>. When you process each`Customer` you compare its node with the first occurrence of the same node in the *key*, if it's the same you process its children (copy the nodes using an identity transform).

This stylesheet will copy all nodes, ignoring the `Orders` subtree and processing only the unique `Customer` nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:r="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS"  
    xmlns="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS"  
    exclude-result-prefixes="r">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="customers" match="r:Customer" use="r:CustomerID"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r:Orders"/>

    <xsl:template match="r:Customers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="r:Customer[generate-id() =
                                   generate-id(key('customers',r:CustomerID)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see the result in this **[XSLT Fiddle no. 1](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpA)**.

**UPDATE** Here is another approach *without using keys**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:r="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS"  
    xmlns="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS"  
    exclude-result-prefixes="r">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="unique-customers" 
                  select="//r:Customer[not(r:CustomerID = following::r:Customer/r:CustomerID)]" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r:Orders"/>

    <xsl:template match="r:Customers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$unique-customers" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result without using keys: **[XSLT Fiddle no. 2](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpA/1)**

Comment: Why is this answer a community wiki? You deserve some upvotes.

Comment: @helderdarocha

Thanks a lot for your help. It works exactly the way I wanted it. but I wanted to achieve this without adding the Key element as Key cannot be used inside the <xsl:template>. Unfortunately I can not use StyleSheet as this would be used inside the BizTalk Scripting functoid that can only take <xsl:template> and not the <xsl:stylesheet>. I will try my best to achieve this based on your sample. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: In this case you can extract the unique `Customer` elements in pure XPath using: `//r:Customer[not(r:CustomerID = following::r:Customer/r:CustomerID)]`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @DanielHaley When I posted it, I discovered an almost identical answer already, but without any explanation, so I decided to not delete mine and leave it as community wiki. This is a common recurring topic and canonical answers might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:c="http://BTDEV:2111/DOWDEN/SPSYS"  exclude-result-prefixes="c">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" />

<xsl:key name="customerList" match="//c:Customer" use="c:CustomerID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//c:Customers"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c:Customers">
<Customers>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="c:Customer[generate-id() =
                    generate-id(key('customerList',c:CustomerID)[1])]"/>
                   </Customers>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I wanted to achieve this without adding the Key element as Key cannot be used inside the <xsl:template>. Unfortunately I can not use StyleSheet as this would be used inside the BizTalk Scripting functoid that can only take <xsl:template> and not the <xsl:stylesheet>. So I could only get what I attempted above.

Comment: Testing code is a good advice, but unspecific. We want to learn from each other.